# LogisticRegression with Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, logistic-regression

I'm using TF 1.10, and I want to use the banking notes [dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/banknote+authentication) to Predict if a Bank Note is forged or not:

```
df_dataset = pd.read_csv(banknote_dataset, header=None, names = CSV_COLUMNS)
df_train, df_valid, df_test = np.split(df_dataset.sample(frac=1), [int(.6*len(df_dataset)), int(.8*len(df_dataset))])

def train_input_fn(df, num_epochs):
  return tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
    x = df,
    y = df[LABEL],
    batch_size = 128,
    num_epochs = num_epochs,
    shuffle = True    
  )

def eval_input_fn(df):
  return tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
    x = df,
    y = df[LABEL],
    batch_size = 128,
    shuffle = False
  )

def prediction_input_fn(df):
  return tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
    x = df,
    y = None,
    batch_size = 128,
    shuffle = False,
  )

def get_feature_cols():
  input_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column(k) for k in FEATURES]
  return input_columns

OUTDIR = 'banknote_trained'
shutil.rmtree(OUTDIR, ignore_errors = True) # start fresh each time

model = tf.estimator.LinearRegressor(
      feature_columns = get_feature_cols(), 
      optimizer=tf.train.FtrlOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1),
      model_dir = OUTDIR)

model.train(input_fn = train_input_fn(df_train, num_epochs = 100))

predictions = model.predict(input_fn = prediction_input_fn(df_test))
for items in predictions:
  print(items)
```

My results are:

```
{'predictions': array([-0.28320795], dtype=float32)}
{'predictions': array([0.8572771], dtype=float32)}
{'predictions': array([0.68809825], dtype=float32)}
{'predictions': array([0.9708319], dtype=float32)}
{'predictions': array([0.0971362], dtype=float32)}
{'predictions': array([0.98395026], dtype=float32)
```

Which according to Logistic Regression, should be between 0 and 1.
Use of Logistic Regression is confusing in TF. Check [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/40071/logistic-regression-with-tensorflow).

Comment: Where did you code the logistic part? The posted code seems to perform a linear regression.

Comment: That's where I'm confused , can't find a way to do it with canned estimator.

Comment: `tf.estimator.LinearClassifier` is basically logistic (softmax) regression.

Comment: Is there a way to do Sigmoid for Binary Classification usingtf.estimator.LinearClassifier ?

Comment: In LinearClassifier I see this: if n_classes == 2:
      head = head_lib._binary_logistic_head_with_sigmoid_cross_entropy_loss(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
          weight_column=weight_column,
          label_vocabulary=label_vocabulary,
          loss_reduction=loss_reduction)  I assume this is Logistic Regression